# Parsing and saving JSON result from GoEuro API

Tags: python, json, api, utf-8

I am new to python so I decided to write a script that parses a json array and writes data in a file.

I wrote the code that does that but I think it can be done way better, So I was hoping to get feedback on how this code can be enhanced and more inline with python best practices.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import json

def get_json(url):
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)


url = ("http://api.goeuro.com/api/v2/position/suggest/en/Berlin")
json_array = get_json(url)

f = open('data.txt', 'w')


for x in json_array:
    gp = x["geo_position"]
    l = gp["latitude"]
    o = gp["longitude"]
    f.write(unicode(x["_id"]).encode("utf-8") +", " +     unicode(x["name"]).encode("utf-8") + ", " + unicode(x["type"]).encode("utf-8")+ ", " + unicode(l).encode("utf-8") + ", " + unicode(o).encode("utf-8") + unicode("\n").encode("utf-8"))

f.close()
```

Also, what is the best way for not having an empty new line at the end of the file ?

Answer (score 2):

- The Python documentation recommends using `with` when dealing with
  files at the bottom of [7.2.1 of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), this has the benefit that you do not have to close the file yourself.
- Although not necessary often a main function is made, so that the
  other functions also can be used as a module. ([6.1.1. Executing
  modules as scripts](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts))
- The long line with the `write` statement can be split over multiple
  lines, you do not need the line joining character (`\`) in this case
  because, [a *closing bracket is still expected* at the end of the
  line](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining).
- The *newline problem*, and simular problems can be solved with the
  [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-functions) function of strings

I took the liberty to create an extra function and all and all i changed your code to:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import json

def get_json(url):
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)

def json_to_formatted_text(geo_data):
    formatted_lines = []
    for x in geo_data:
        gp = x["geo_position"]
        l = gp["latitude"]
        o = gp["longitude"]
        line = (unicode(x["_id"]).encode("utf-8")  + ", " +
                unicode(x["name"]).encode("utf-8") + ", " + 
                unicode(x["type"]).encode("utf-8") + ", " + 
                unicode(l).encode("utf-8")         + ", " + 
                unicode(o).encode("utf-8")         + 
                unicode("\n").encode("utf-8"))
        formatted_lines.append(line)
    return unicode("\n").encode("utf-8").join(formatted_lines)

def main(): 
    url = ("http://api.goeuro.com/api/v2/position/suggest/en/Berlin")
    json_array = get_json(url)
    out_text   = json_to_formatted_text(json_array)
    with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(out_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@JanKulken's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/143455/98493), you could simplify the function `json_to_formatted_text` even more by defining a helper function to do the encoding, define a constant for the encoding of a line-break and then use `str.format` in that function:

```
def _encode(s):
    return unicode(s).encode("utf-8")

LINEBREAK = _encode("\n")


def json_to_formatted_text(geo_data):
    formatted_lines = []
    for x in geo_data:
        x["lat"] = x["geo_position"]["latitude"]
        x["lon"] = x["geo_position"]["longitude"]
        line = _encode("{name}, {type}, {lat}, {lon}\n".format(**x))
        formatted_lines.append(line)
    return LINEBREAK.join(formatted_lines)
```

(The other functions are the same as in his answer.)